# Finding all solutions of a polynomial in Z mod 14

Tags: real-analysis

Find all solutions of $x^2 +x - 6 = 0$ in the ring $Z/14$.

I first factor this expression as $(x+3)(x-2)$. I then realize that gcd(2,14) = 2 and gcd(3,14) is 1, so 3 is a unit and 2 is a zero divider of this ring, I am not sure how to make use of these facts here though. Z/14 is NOT a domain so it makes this a bit tricky.

Comment: Can't you just say that for (x + 3)(x - 2) == 0 mod 14 you must have: either x + 3 = 0, x - 2 = 0, or one is 2 and the other is 7.

Comment: that's the thing: Z/14 is not a domain, i.e, for ab = 0 it is not always true both a and b are non zero to multiply to zero.

Comment: I understand, but the only other case you have is that a = 7 (mod 14) and b = 2 (mod 14), or vice versa.

Comment: i understand that too. so really what i'm asking is, is the fact that 2 is a non zero divisor and 3 a unit not significant to this problem?

Comment: not really.  What you are thinking of these quantities as is $a = x + 3$ and $b = x - 2$ and considering all possible ways $ab = 0$ in your ring.  The possible ways in your ring being, $a$ or $b$ is 0, or one is 7 and the other is 2.

Comment: well, in the previous problem i did, i was working in the ring M3(R) and I had to find solutions to X^2 = I^3, and writing X^2 - I^3 = 0 and factoring i get a similar expression, but this provides a false result as there are many ways to multiply two non-zero matrices to get the zero matrix.

Comment: So, in hindsight, the method didn't work because "there are just too many ways to multiply two non-zero matrices to get the zero matrix."  Ie, finding all $a$ and $b$ such that $ab = 0$ is just not feasible?  It should give you the correct answer, however, if you go through them all.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ mod $\,2\,$ it is $\,x(x\!+\!1) \equiv 0,\,$ so $x \equiv 0,1,\,$ and $\,7\mid (x\!+\!3)(x\!-\!2)\!\iff\! 7\mid x+3\,$ or $\,7\mid x-2.\,$ So $\,{\rm mod}\ 7\!:\ x\equiv 2\,$ or $\,-3\equiv 4,\,$ so $\,{\rm mod}\ 14\!:\ x \equiv 2,\,2\!+\!7,\,$ or $\, 4,\,4\!+\!7,\,$ since all values mod $2$ work.

Comment: hm, can you go a bit slower? I think im getting the gist of this but I don't have enough number theory knowledge to fully understand why we're talking mod 2 and 7 here. (im thinking CRT but im not so good at this_

Comment: Please say more precisely where you are stuck.

Comment: okay, i think i understand now. you are using the chinese remainder theorem to build solutions mod 14, by breaking 14 into prime factors, am i correct?

Comment: @fur CRT is overkill here. It's easy to show that $\, x\equiv a\pmod m\iff x\equiv a,\, a\!+\!m\pmod{2m}$.

Comment: how did you get 2 and 4? I got 0 and 1 from mod 2 and 2 and 4 from mod 7 like you, so when I considered what x is mod 14 when its 0 mod 2 i got 0,2,4,6, etc (im doing the CRT method). basically, i got that 9 and 11 work like you did but i dont know how you got 2 and 4. what do you mean by "all values mod 2 work" ?

Comment: As I said in the prior comment $\ x\equiv 2\pmod 7\!\iff\!x\equiv 2,\, 2\!+\!7\pmod{14}.\,$ And similarly $\ x\equiv 4\pmod 7\!\iff\!x\equiv 4,\, 4\!+\!7\pmod{14}.\,$ They're all solutions mod $2$ because every value is.

Comment: ok, all of that makes sense, thanks. but what doesnt make sense is this: what happens to the congruences mod 2 that you originally stated?: we have x = 0 and 1 mod 2 as solutions of this equation mod 2, but they werent present in the final solution.